# Как получить список кодеков, поддерживаемых текущим android устройством?

Tags: java, android

Пример списка кодеков из AIDA64:
[image: List codecs from AIDA64]

Comment: Отредактировал вопрос

Comment: [Get supported Codec for Android device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11791473/get-supported-codec-for-android-device), [supported codecs in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4920605/supported-codecs-in-android)

Comment: getCodecCount() и getCodecInfoAt() устарели. Я гуглил перед тем, как задавать вопрос и натыкался на эти ссылки

Comment: В доках почти всегда написано чем заменить - читайте внимательнее. Для API>=21 используйте `getCodecInfos()` - он выдаст массив и вы его раскрутите в цикле, как обычно.

Comment: Если у вас появился ответ на вопрос, пишите его в ответе, а не в вопросе

Answer (score 1):

```java
    public List<Info> getCodecList() {
        List<Info> codecsInfo = new ArrayList<Info>();

        MediaCodecInfo[] mediaCodecInfo = getMediaCodecInfo();
        for (int i = 0; i < mediaCodecInfo.length; i++) {
            codecsInfo.add(new Info(mediaCodecInfo[i].getName(), getMimeTypes(mediaCodecInfo[i])));
        }

        return codecsInfo;
    }

    private MediaCodecInfo[] getMediaCodecInfo() {
        MediaCodecList mediaCodecList = new MediaCodecList(MediaCodecList.ALL_CODECS);
        return mediaCodecList.getCodecInfos();
    }

    private String getMimeTypes(MediaCodecInfo mediaCodecInfo) {
        String mime = "";

        String[] supportedTypes = mediaCodecInfo.getSupportedTypes();
        for (int i = 0; i < supportedTypes.length; i++) {
            mime += supportedTypes[i] + "\n";
        }

        return mime;
    }
```

Класс Info:

```java
public class Info {
    private String title;
    private String content;

    public Info(String title, String content){
        this.title = title;
        this.content = content;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }

    public void setContent(String content) {
        this.content = content;
    }
}
```